Solana on-chain anchor program maintenance
I'm currently working with the Anchor framework on the Solana blockchain and I would like to know the best practices for maintaining an Anchor program. Specifically, I'm interested in the following aspects:
Error: Deploying program failed: RPC response error -32002: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: account data too small for instruction [3 log messages]
There was a problem deploying: Output { status: ExitStatus(unix_wait_status(256)), stdout: "", stderr: "" }.

After some upgrades using anchor deploy, I am facing this error.
To deploy, I should have created new program address and deployed to new account. But in that case we can lose program account data.
I am really curious how to resolve this issue.
I really appreciate someone who helps this issue.
I am trying to know how to upgrade solana on-chain program using anchor.

I found the solution by myself.
I tried to generated new Pubkey for deploying solana-program and replaced it in lib.rs file in Anchor project.
declare_id!("BRBjZvw1di9ALUUVHrMpyTftRCFcShYMvCPDNRFx3t2s");

And replace deploy/.keypair.json file.
anchor build

And deploy
anchor deploy

On mainnet, we spent real SOL so we need to refund it when we are going to deploy in new account.
We can do that by following command.
solana program close --buffers

Thanks for all contributors to my answer.

If you haven't allocated or changed the program account data size, you might encounter problems because the new program size exceeds the existing program size.
You might need to increase the program size in this way:
solana program extend <program-id> 200000

Please check compiled .so file size and deployed program size again.

Actually, it's fine for first or second deploy. This error occurs from third deploy.
What's the problem?

Can you share more detailed error message?

Error message is the same as I posted.
But that error occured after upgrading program 3~4 times.

Did you try to extend program size as I posted?
